# Virt manager error: unable to find any master var store for loader

Tags: linux-kvm, virt-manager

I followed the guide here https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM but I got an error after importing the VM into virt-manager. Specifically, I get the error 'unable to find any master var store for loader'

I checked that the file exists and redownloaded it from the github repo but no luck. I even had an error which said Permission denied when I ran this command `virsh --connect qemu:///system define macOS.xml` so I had to add sudo and ended up with the error that I said

If it helps, I'm running Fedora 34

```
Full trace: 

Error starting domain: operation failed: unable to find any master var store for loader: /home/NAME/OSX-KVM/OVMF_CODE.fd

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 65, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 101, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1329, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1353, in create
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: operation failed: unable to find any master var store for loader: /home/NAME/OSX-KVM/OVMF_CODE.fd
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, all my xml files (in the 'Virtual Hardware details' menu in virt-manager) were looking for /home/root/OSX-KVM but it didn't exist because my whole OSX-KVM git was in my main user folder. So I updated all the directories and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll write here.

For me OVMF_VARS-1024x768.fd was missing.

So I did `git checkout OVMF_VARS-1024x768.fd`

So I'm assuming one of the OVMF_VARS files is missing for you as well.

Comment: I had the same file missing. With that file, I can get to the boot menu, select MacOS, it starts loading and jams before showing the UI, and that file is deleted again. Got an idea what else I'm missing? Clicking on `OpenCore-Boot.sh` to start the instance works though.